# UIScrollView setContentSize breaks view with Auto Layout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, autolayout

I am using Auto Layout in my iPhone app and have a `UIScrollView`. I need to change the content size of my scroll view at several points while my apps running (so setting the content size in `viewWillAppear` is useless as I have seen this suggested in other places).

When I change it, my subviews jump about, presumably because it breaks the auto layout constraints.

So how can I approach changing my scrollview content size with auto layout enabled?

Thanks.

Comment: Try it in viewDidAppear instead of in viewWillAppear

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I of course set the content size initially when the view loads/appears, but I also need to change it multiple times in the same view after it loads/appears in my own methods. This is my issue.

Comment: 1. Maybe your view is too complicated for the auto layout. 2. You have not specified the correct auto layout constraints, try some other constraints. 3. Use code in viewWillLayoutSubviews to layout your subview manually.

Comment: did you solve the problem ?

Comment: @JoshKahane - did you get a chance to try viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was having this same issue, and I know this can't be the final solution, but for now, rather than calling this in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, by putting the code inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews` it allowed me to set the contentSize AFTER the viewController did it's default business :)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Test your code in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`. Apple say:

> When a view’s bounds change, the view adjusts the position of its
>   subviews. Your view controller can override this method to make
>   changes before the view lays out its subviews. The default
>   implementation of this method does nothing.

[UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)