# UIScrollView with AutoLayout does not work as expected

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a `UIViewController` which has the following structure:

View
 -> ScrollView
   -> View
     -> All sorts of stuff

I read that its best to put the "all sorts of stuff" inside a view inside the scrollview. Everything worked perfectly until I had to support iPhone 5 and use AutoLayout. Now scrollviews have become the bane of my existence.

How can I get the scrollview to scroll properly? I've tried all manner of things and it just simply does not work correctly, or if it works it constantly wants to scroll to the top or when navigating back to the screen the content offset is wrong.

Currently I have the following to make the scrollview semi-work:

```
public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
    View.LayoutIfNeeded();
    scrollView.ContentSize = scrollView.Subviews[0].Frame.Size;
}
```

What is the correct way of doing this using AutoLayout? It shoundn't be this hard! There must be a way to get it right with IB or in code...

Comment: Is the value produced by `scrollView.Subviews[0].Frame.Size` the correct size (that is, large enough to require scrolling to resolve)?

Comment: Yeah the inner view is sized perfectly in IB to hold all the fields inside. Without autolayout the scrollview's content size was being set in the ViewDidLoad method and things worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is unnecessary. If you are using IB make sure that the UIScrollView's "Bottom Space to: View" constraint equals Default. You can do this by checking the "Standard" checkbox when editing the constraint.

The UIScrollView will still behave strangely if you scroll away from the starting position, navigate to another page and navigate back. You can fix this by resetting the UIScrollView's contentOffset to (0, 0) in ViewWillAppear:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        scrollView.ContentOffset = new PointF(0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: For some unknown reason, setting the Bottom Space to View to Default fixed the vast majority of my problems. Thanks David.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what you need to do to get `UIScrollView` and AutoLayout work together nicely:

- Create a `UIScrollView` and attach constraints to its parent view
- Add your subviews. For AutoLayout to be able to know the size of the contentView, there need to be constraints from top to bottom, left to right. Another (easier but less pretty) way to solve this is to add a `UIView` to the scrollview and pin its width and/or height. Add the real contents of the `UIScrollView` to the `UIView`.

The system is awesome, once you get the hang of it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think that function you have going on there is unnecessary, there's probably something you're missing in regards to what the Autolayout system is attempting to accomplish with your view.

After searching around, I found a couple of threads.

There's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13439304/uiscrollview-setcontentsize-breaks-view-with-auto-layout), where the accepted solution is changing the contentSize *after* layout by using `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.  Seems hacky.

Overall, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13548039/700471) is a good general description of what you are doing with ScrollViews in AutoLayout, and he links to [the iOS 6 release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html) (search UIScrollView) where Apple gives several examples of how to make ScrollViews correctly.  I'm sure that you'll be able to handle it with that.

Also, although it's not entirely clear from your question, if you think that maybe some of your layout constraints are breaking, you can see this output in the debugger--nice big blocks of statements saying precisely what constraints cannot be satisfied and why, which, after some deciphering, may point to the source of your problem.  That might not be related at all, because it sounds like you're simply not using the system at all, but it's data you might not have.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to set contentSize at viewDidAppear so you negate the effects of autolayout.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     [yourScrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, 400))];
}
```